# C# Access to GSuite emails without oAuth screen (console app as task)

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I'm trying to fetch emails from a GSuite email account.
I've tried everything I found on internet but I can't find the right way to do it.

I have Gsuite administration credentials, I have created my service account, activated domain delegation, created my project, activated gmail api, added the authorization to my service account into ManageOAuthClients page from admin.google.com (set to the https://mail.google.com/). I have downloaded secret json and service account json.

I tried many sources but everything that seems to works is using oAuth flow (with web authorization asked to the user).
I need to avoid this because I'm developping a console app that will be a scheduled task so it should run without human intervention.

It's been a day long I'm searching, trying but not finding anything working.
Any idea please ?

Comment: Excuse me if it's not exactly what you ask for, but have you [**tried this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802598/send-emails-from-my-gmail-account-with-oauth2-and-nodemailer#answer-42804591)?

Comment: I tried, but I don't understand where to begin : I tried the playground site with a simple "other" Oauth client ID with its secret => playground website tells me that I have to set a good redirect uri. Ok but I don't want this web flow part...
Seriously, Google could have made a simplier thing... 
So at this moment, I can't do anything with this playground site because it uses a web site flow that I don't want.